# React Styled components and css, h1 isn't displayed

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, google-maps, styled-components

I'm trying to style a google maps component and add a header with h1 on it.
adding the header background on the map works, but adding the h1 doesn't work, not matter how I format its position.

The headers CSS

```js
export const HeaderBackground = styled.div`
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  height: 54px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
`;

export const Header = styled.h1`
  font-family: ${fontFamilies.SourceSansPro};
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  height: 15px;
  color: #009cde;
  text-shadow: 6px 6px 24px #24415d29;
`;
```

The map's CSS

```js
export const ProcessorMapContainer = styled.div`
    position: absolute;
    top: 54px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
`;
```

the main map component:

```js
const ProcessorMap = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const defaultZoom = useSelector(getMapZoom);
    const defaultCenter = useSelector(getMapLocation);
    const markerList = useSelector(getFarmLocations);
    // const userName = useSelector(getUserName)

    const props = {
        defaultZoom,
        defaultCenter,
        markerList,
    };


    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getFarmLocationAction());
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, []);

    return (
        <ProcessorMapContainer>
            <HeaderBackground></HeaderBackground>
            <Header></Header>
            <Map {...props} />
        </ProcessorMapContainer>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue that you are having is that your tag is empty, which is rendering:

```html
<h1></h1>
```

so, just add some content inside your `<Header>`.

```
const name = 'Abraham';

return (
    <ProcessorMapContainer>
        <HeaderBackground />
        <Header>{name}</Header>
        <Map {...props} />
     </ProcessorMapContainer>
);
```